# jQuery after submit data doesnt show succes view, but data input to database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

i have a little problem here with jQuery.
i have made a submit form with this following code :

```
<form class="form-inline" id="newslatter" role="form" >
    <select name="city" id='city' class="form-control">
        <option value="<?=$id?>">Singapore</option>
    </select>

    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="<?=$this->lang->line('footer_enter_email')?>" value="<?=(isset($json)?$json["email"]:"")?>">
    <label id="emptyemail" style="color:indianred"><?php echo form_error('email'); ?></label>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success input"><?=$this->lang->line('footer_signup_now')?></button>
</form>
<div id="register_complete" style="display: none;color:whitesmoke;">
        <p align="center">Congratulations, You have been added to our Newsletter
        Thank you for your registration. From now on you will receive updates about exclusive offers in your city.</p>
</div>
```

and this is my jQuery :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function validateEmail(email) {
    var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
    return regex.test(email);
}
$("#newslatter").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var email= $("#email").val();
    var city=$("#city").val();
    var something_wrong="";
    var agreement = $('#agreement input[type="checkbox"]').is(":checked");

    if(email.length == 0){
        $("#emptyemail").html("Please fill in Email field");
        $("#email").focus();
        something_wrong=true;
    }else if(!validateEmail(email)){
        $("#emptyemail").html("insert valid email address!");
        something_wrong=true;
    }else{ $("#emptyemail").html(""); something_wrong=false; }

    if(agreement == false ){
        $("#notagree").html("You should read and accept Terms and conditions and Privacy Policy");
        something_wrong=true;
    }else{ $("#notagree").html("");  something_wrong=false;}
    if( something_wrong == true) return false;

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/newslatter",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {pcity:city,pemail:email},
        success: function(res) {
            if (res)
            {
               if(res.message != "success"){
                   $("#emptyemail").html(res.message);
                   return false;
               }else{
                   $("#newslatter").hide();
                   $("#register_complete").show();
               }
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

and this is my ajax controller:

```
Function newslatter(){
    $city_id=$this->input->post('pcity',true);
    $email = $this->input->post("pemail",true);
    $query= $this->ajax_m->m_check_email($email);

    if(strlen($email)==0){
        $data["message"]= "Please fill in Email field";
    }else{
        if($query != null){
            $data["message"]= "E-mail already registered";
        }else{
            $this->ajax_m->m_insert_newslatter($city_id,$email);
            $data["message"]= "success";
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the following model for ajax :

```
Function m_check_email($email){
    $sql="SELECT `email` FROM `uhd_newslatter` WHERE `email` = '$email'";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql)->row_array();
    return $query;
}

Function m_insert_newslatter($city,$email){
    $sql="INSERT INTO `uhd_newslatter` (`singapore_address_id` , `email`) VALUES ($city,'$email')";
    $this->db->query($sql);
}
```

those are all my code. my problems are :

if i submit data, data send into my database, but after that there is nothing happening in my view, actually if submit process is success there will be show my success message, and all my submit form will be hide

and, if i use the same email, if i submit it, it should be show a message that i put it ajax controller. but data isn't input to database.

guys can you help me whats wrong on my code?

sorry if i have so many part of code (:

Comment: need return value in `newslatter` function

Comment: i have right? @Saty

Comment: function newslatter should return value ,in your case it is  $data["message"], you have echo these value  on ajax page, so these message will be return on success.

Comment: how to get that can u help me please? i really stuck in jquery @user3782114

Comment: instead of using array for return value($data["message"]) in newslatter function , store string in variable, it will make things easy for you....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ajax writen dataType:'json', but in your controller there is json_encode($yourdata); that will be read in success ajax. Because of that, your success is not executed.

```
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/newslatter",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {pcity:city,pemail:email},
        success: function(res) { //controller has to make json_encode($data); for product res value.
            if (res)
            {
               if(res.message != "success"){
                   $("#emptyemail").html(res.message);
                   return false;
               }else{
                   $("#newslatter").hide();
                   $("#register_complete").show();
               }
            }
        }
    });
```

Your controller need to be added echo json_encode($data);

```
Function newslatter(){
    $city_id=$this->input->post('pcity',true);
    $email = $this->input->post("pemail",true);
    $query= $this->ajax_m->m_check_email($email);

    if(strlen($email)==0){
        $data["message"]= "Please fill in Email field";
    }else{
        if($query != null){
            $data["message"]= "E-mail already registered";
        }else{
            $this->ajax_m->m_insert_newslatter($city_id,$email);
            $data["message"]= "success";
        }
    }
echo json_encode($data);//add this line
}
```

Comment: than what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please update your newsletter function with this code:

```
function newslatter(){
    $data =array();
    $city_id=$this->input->post('pcity',true);
    $email = $this->input->post("pemail",true);
    $query= $this->ajax_m->m_check_email($email);

    if(strlen($email)==0){
        $data["message"]= "Please fill in Email field";
    }else{
        if($query != null){
            $data["message"]= "E-mail already registered";
        }else{
            $this->ajax_m->m_insert_newslatter($city_id,$email);
            $data["message"]= "success";
        }
    }
    return json_encode($data);
}
```